# Call a function in every onFailure block in AndroidAsyncHTTP

Tags: android, optimization, android-async-http

I'm using the `android-async-http` library in many locations in my app. My usual `onFailure()` block looks something like this:

```java
APIClient.POST("/user/login", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
        // Do onSuccess stuff...
    }

    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject error) {
        Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(), 
            "Something Went Wrong!", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show();

        // Other onFailure stuff
    }
});
```

---

So I'm basically showing this Toast in every `onFailure` block. Isn't there a better way to do this? Can't I do something in the original `APIClient.POST()` method to do this for me every time? So, If I don't override the onFailure block for one call, it still shows this Toast. Here's my `APIClient.POST` method:

```java
public static void POST(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
    // Maybe do somesthing with responseHandler here before passing it off to AsyncHttpClient?
    client.post(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
}
```

Appreciate any help I could get. Thanks!

Comment: you could just extend the ApiClient and use this version

Comment: This is a good question, let me try something and get back to you.

Comment: @A.S. - Can you post an example? I'm not really sure what to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this, and use this class instead of the JsonHttpResponse:

```
public class MyJsonHttpResponseHandler extends JsonHttpResponseHandler {

    private Context context;

    public MyJsonHttpResponseHandler(Context context){
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
        Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "Something Went Wrong!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show();

    }
}
```

Use it like this

```
APIClient.POST("/user/login", params, new MyJsonHttpResponseHandler(getActivity()){ ....
```

Comment: Awesome! Also, would I need to call `super()` in the `onFailure` block as well?

Comment: @Pervert-san No. Unless you are overriding the method and adding something to it (Like show another toast with this one), you do not need to call super(). If you don't override onFailure() from your implementing class, it will be called automatically without super().